# ReactTestUtils Simulate.click() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, karma-runner, sinon-chai

I am trying to run a test that is meant to check if my React component's Add button gets clicked, so that a spy can catch that the appropriate method is being called and pass the test.

However I am encountering an error with ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click() in which it returns undefined and my spy never sees that the method is hit.

I am using react, sinon-chai, and karma.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import AddItem from '../AddItem';

describe('<AddItem />', () => {
  let component;

beforeEach(function() {
  buildAddItem();
});

function buildAddItem(displayError = false) {
  let props = {
     displayError: displayError,
     text: 'test'
  };
  component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<AddItem {...props}/>);
  return component;
}

it('submits a new item to the database', () => {
   let callback = sinon.spy(component, 'handleSubmit');
   let input = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'input');
   let btn = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'button');

   input.value = "test";
   component.setState({ text: 'test ' });
   ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(input);

   ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(btn);

   expect(component.handleSubmit.CalledOnce).to.be.true;
 });
});
```

I've tried multiple things, including doing a .findDOMNode() and .getDOMNode() on btn but i just receive an error about it not being an object.

I am unsure what else to do to get passed this issue.

Comment: just to make sure, Simulate.change(input) works fine?

Comment: @JordanHendrix  It also returns undefined when I log it.

Comment: Did you npm install it?

Comment: @JordanHendrix Yes, I npm installed react-addons-test-utils

Comment: Name your spy onClick... And another one for onChange...

Comment: @JordanHendrix Okay, I've done it. onChange gets called and returns true, but onClick still comes back false and fails.

Comment: Add the new code to your question please